# Retrieve a variable value from a table cell in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How do I retrieve a variable value from a table cell using javascript.

```
var clicks = new Array();
var click1;
var click2;

function addTableRow() {
click1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('caption').value),10;
click2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('caption1').value),10;
var clicks = [click1, click2];
clicks.push({c1:clicks[0], c2:clicks[1]});

var table = document.getElementById('table');
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute("type", "text");
input.style.width = "100px";
cell2.appendChild(input);

cell3.innerHTML = "x:" + clicks[0] + ", y:" + clicks[1];

var btnDelete = document.createElement('Button');
var btnDeleteText = document.createTextNode("Delete");
btnDelete.appendChild(btnDeleteText);
btnDelete.style.width = "80px";
cell4.appendChild(btnDelete);

btnDelete.onclick = function() {
var rowToDelete = this.parentNode.parentNode;
var parentReference = rowToDelete.parentNode;
parentReference.removeChild(rowToDelete);

var inputsInTable = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(i=0; i<inputsInTable.length; i++)
{

  ??????????????????????

}
}
}
```

Basically, when I add a row the clicks get stored in the array. When I delete a row, I need to update the array by rebuilding it.
I hope it's more clear now.
Any help would be very appreciated.

Marco

Comment: So if I understand right, you get values `clicks` and you append it to table. Then on some event, you wish to read these values and save it in array. Am I right?

Comment: Do you mean retrieving value of cell equal to the text in the cell ?
If that then you can do it using simple jquery click event.

var clicks = [];
$('td').on('click', function(){
     clicks.push($(this).text());
});

Let me know if you are looking for something else.

Comment: Yes Rajesh, your first comment is right. I show these 2 variables that I get from another function and show them in the cell. Then I want to store them from the cell into the array. I can't do it directly from the other function because I delete rows from the table and the array has to be updated all the time by reading from the cells. I'll be using a loop for that. I know how to do that. I need only to store these variables into the array

Comment: Can you show us your html? Because you can get the cell with a selector something like `document.querySelector('the_table td').innerHTML` but to be more specific I need to see your html.

Comment: Too much code is missing. We need a js fiddle yo help you. ;-)